# Set PivotTable field calculation as DifferenceFrom next

Tags: c#, pivot-table, office-interop, excel-interop

I try to set a calculation of a field in a pivot table created with office.interop

I  need to set DifferenceFromNext, but in the enums i found just DifferenceFrom

```
var field = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields((item as PropertyAggregateDescription).PropertyName));
field.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
field.Function = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum;

field.Calculation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldCalculation.xlDifferenceFrom;
```

The problem is that it calculate on the wrong field

Comment: I can not access PivotFields via c# and microsoft.office.interop.excel\15.0.4795.1000\

Answer (score 0):

Solved setting the base item, be sure of setting before the calculation and then the base item, instead fire an exception

```
 field.Calculation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldCalculation.xlDifferenceFrom;
 field.BaseItem = "(next)";
```